# I am unable to use TouchImageView dependency

Tags: android, kotlin, imageview

I'm trying to use the dependency of TouchImageView for android. I'm unable to use the functions in the class and getting this error in Log
[1]: https://github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView

### Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':hideItPro:mergeDebugNativeLibs'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':hideItPro:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
> Could not resolve com.github.MikeOrtiz:TouchImageView:1.1.1.
> Required by:
> project :hideItPro
> > Could not resolve com.github.MikeOrtiz:TouchImageView:1.1.1.
> > Could not get resource 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/moat-sdk-builds/com/github/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView/1.1.1/TouchImageView-1.1.1.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/moat-sdk-builds/com/github/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView/1.1.1/TouchImageView-1.1.1.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
  ==============================================================================
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.5/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 27s
303 actionable tasks: 270 executed, 33 up-to-date

Answer (score 1):

**In settings.gradle**

```
   dependencyResolutionManagement {
        repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
        repositories {
            google()
            mavenCentral()
//here the dependency
            maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
            jcenter() // Warning: this repository is going to shut down soon
        }
    }
    
    include ':app'
    rootProject.name = "Apk"
```

this worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Add maven repository in project build.gradle file,

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        ...
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

Add dependencies in app build.gradle file,

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation 'com.github.MikeOrtiz:TouchImageView:1.4.1' // last SupportLib version
    // or
    implementation 'com.github.MikeOrtiz:TouchImageView:$LAST_VERSION' // Android X
}
```